# Boto3 create a new lambda layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to **create a new layer** for lambda via boto3 (python).

I didn't find an example in AWS docs.

Example for creating layer via AWS site :
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use [`publish_layer_version()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.publish_layer_version):

> Creates an AWS Lambda layer from a ZIP archive. Add layers to your function with `CreateFunction` or `UpdateFunctionConfiguration`.